# Prove $\overline{E}$ is closed. Question about proof.

Tags: general-topology

To prove $\overline{E}$ is closed, we need to show that $(\overline{E})' \subset \overline{E}$.

We know $\overline{E} = E \cup E'$. So $(\overline{E})' = E' \cup (E')'$. One can prove that $E'$ is closed. Thus, $(E')' \subset E'$.

Here is where I get confused. My instructor says:

Therefore, $(\overline{E})' \subset E'$.

Shouldn't my instructor mean $(\overline{E})' = E'$? I mean, if $A = B \cup C$ and we show that $C \subset B$, then doesn't $A = B$?

Either way, the conclusion of the proof is the same, I just don't understand this intermediate step. To conclude the proof we note that $E' \subset \overline{E}$. Therefore, since $(\overline{E})' \subset \overline{E}$, $\overline{E}$ is closed.

Comment: Generally $\overline E$ means the closure of a set which is basically closed by definition (depending on the definition), so at this level it would be very helpful if you would tell us exactly how you define $\overline E$ and $E'$.

Comment: We define $\overline{E} = E \cup E'$. That's all we have to work with.

Comment: You still need to define $E'$.

Comment: @Jim My guess would be the set of limit points.